# If `new int` returns an `int*`, then why doesn't `new int[n]` return an `int**`?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory, free

I am puzzled how both `new int` and `new int[n]` return an `int*`. Why doesn't the latter return an `int**`?

Here is some context: refer to the variable `data` below in a snippet from Goodrich, Tamassia, and Mount's 2nd ed. Data Structures and Algs in C++ textbook:

```
class Vect {
   public:
      Vect(int n);
       ~Vect();
      // ... other public members omitted
   private:
      int* data;
      int size;
};
    
Vect::Vect(int n) {
    size = n;
    data = new int[n];
}
    
Vect::~Vect() {
    delete [] data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`new int[n]` cannot return a result of type `int**` because an `int**` value has to point to an *object* of type `int*` (a pointer object).

`new int[n]` allocates memory for an array of `n` objects, each of which is of type `int`. It does not create a pointer object.

The `int*` value it returns points to the initial (0th) element of the allocated array. Other elements of the array can be accessed by pointer arithmetic.

It *could* have been defined to yield a result of type `int (*)[n]`, which is a pointer to an array of `n` `int` elements, except that (a) C++ doesn't permit arrays with non-constant bounds, and (b) even for something like `int (*)[4]`, it's less convenient that `int*`.

C++, like its ancestor language C, treats arrays as second-class citizens. Array expressions, in most but not all contexts, are "converted" (adjusted at compile time) to pointer expressions, pointing to the initial element of the array object, and array elements are accessed using pointer arithmetic. (The indexing operator `a[i]` is syntactic sugar for `*(a+i)`).

Yes, it can all be confusing and counterintuitive.

Recommended reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com) (most of it applies to both C and C++).